# Can't ssh to server running bridged network connection

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I have a server with a bridged network interface. /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0

auto xenbr0
```

And iptables -S:

```
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

When I first boot the machine, I can't ssh to it from somewhere else on the network. However if I run:

```
ifdown xenbr0
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
ifup xenbr0
```

I can ssh in.

For some reason something is different when the machine boots and I can't ssh unless I take down xenbr0 and eth0 and bring them back up.

What do I need to do to be able to ssh in straight away without having to go through this?

Comment: What you've posted seems confused.  You want `eth0` **both** to be part of a bridge **and** to have a DHCP-assigned ip address?  That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: This is for Xen VMs. It works just fine. Is it not usual for a bridge to have an IP address as well as the physical interface?

How would you have it set up?

Comment: It's completely normal for a bridge to have an address - but not so the enslaved interfaces.  And if you'll forgive me, it's not working just fine - or you wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: My apologies, I should have said that the VM is working fine.

How can you set up eth0 to not use DHCP or a static address? If those options are left off it's not possible to bring up eth0.

Comment: Don't give it either.  Any address you want `eth0` to have should be assigned to, or acquired by, the bridge, instead.

Comment: Are you saying that I should remove the eth0 line _completely_ or just change it to iface eth0 ?

Comment: Beats me, I'm not a debian guy.  What I'm saying is that *any* addresses you want this system to have should be loaded onto the bridge interface, not onto any enslaved members.

Answer (score 1):

Once an interface is enslaved as a bridge port, it cannot use addresses. If you want to assign IPs or do DHCP, you need to do that on the bridge interface it is assigned to.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How would I do that in /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score 1):

The interfaces configuration that worked looked like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0

auto xenbr0
```

The two eth0 lines are now different.

Comment: If this is solved, please mark it as solved by ticking the check mark so that it turns green.